# Activity MainActivity has leaked ServiceConnection azu@42be3310 that was originally bound here

Tags: android

I can't get rid of this error message

> E/ActivityThread: Activity com.example.project.MainActivity has leaked
>   ServiceConnection azu@42be3310 that was originally bound here
>                                                                         android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity
>   com.example.project.MainActivity has leaked ServiceConnection
>   azu@42be3310 that was originally bound here
>                                                                             at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.(LoadedApk.java:979)
>                                                                             at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:873)
>                                                                             at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1690)
>                                                                             at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1673)
>                                                                             at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:517)
>                                                                             at bye.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:127)
>                                                                             at bye.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:144)
>                                                                             at pg.b(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:348)
>                                                                             at pg.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:190)
>                                                                             at il.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:5176)
>                                                                             at im.run(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:1042)
>                                                                             at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
>                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>                                                                             at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>                                                                             at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>                                                                             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

Answer (score 3):

This is usually a result of a Service being bound when an Activity is dismissed. I've solved it before by keeping a boolean value in the Activity that keeps track of whether or not the Service is bound. Then in `onDestroy` check if the Service is still bound with the boolean instance variable and unbind the Service if it is still bound.

I also do my initial binding of the Service in `onResume` while checking to make sure it isn't already bound with my boolean instance variable just in case